# Android: Is it possible to calculate a view's height before it's drawn?

Tags: android, android-layout

Notes:

- **I don't want to use any getViewTreeObserver() listeners, or any listeners at all.** I want to calculate the view's height **BEFORE** it's drawn.
- I tried getMeasuredHeight() but it returns 0 every time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tried first `View#measure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` ?

Comment: first measure your view, then get measured height

Comment: Alright I just tried it and I get incorrect values... I read Java's explanation about measures, but I still didn't find a way to calculate the correct height after draw. I wonder why people say it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getViewTreeObserver(). One thing you can do is have the visibility in the view set to visible or invisible to start with(just so that a height is created) and then change it to invisible/gone in the code. Example:

```
private int mHeight = 0;
private View mView;

class...

// onCreate or onResume or onStart ...
mView = findViewByID(R.id.someID);
mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // gets called after layout has been done but before display
        // so we can get the height then hide the view


        mHeight = mView.getHeight(); 

        mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener( this );
        mView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }

});
```

Comment: There's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there IS another way, I used to use it for some custom stuff but it will definetely work for you

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       void run() {
            if(view.getHeight() == 0) {
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
            } else {
                 // you're all set
            }
       }
}, 50);
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly like calling onGlobalLayoutListener(). The view is drawn and then the handler returns its height. I want to calculate the height BEFORE the view is drawn.

Comment: then WHY do you want to do it this way? may be there is another workarround, because it doesn't make any sense

Comment: I'm trying to set a custom height for Gridview's items. Setting the params to GridView.AUTO_FIT or simillars results in messy size changes in the UI, because each item loads an Image. I tried everything from setting a default fixed-size image source to playing with the ImageView's scale types, but none worked.
What I do now is set a fixed number as the GridView's height. In my phone it looks good, but in others it doesn't always.

*Oh and yes, I'm using Picasso.